# Can a word have two meanings at the same time?

Tags: word-usage

“The” can’t be used twice.

Ex) The the Greens are famous X

But I need to use two “the”s for indicating a family surname and specific thing, but “the” can’t be used twice.

Then, one “the” has two meanings?

Comment: I'm not clear why you want to use "the" twice.  The sentence "The Greens are famous whatevers." is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle you can construct sentences which have two "the"s.  For example, there's a novel called "The Firm", which was adapted into a popular movie.  So you could, in principle, say "The 'The Firm' movie is good."

In practice, we almost never do this.  If "'The Firm' is good" were felt to be too ambiguous, we would say "The movie of 'The Firm' is good."

In other cases, one of the "the"s gets dropped.  For example, in the UK there's a newspaper called *The Times*.  The "The" is part of its title and some style guides (not all) require it to be capitalised.  But we would never refer to an article in the paper as "the *The Times* article" - we'd say either "the *Times* article" or "the article in *The Times*".

While you can contrive cases where "the the" is grammatically correct, we virtually always avoid it.

If I were correcting a sentence you'd written and I felt that you should omit the word "the", I could say "You should take the 'the' out."  But I'd be more likely to say, "You should take the word 'the' out."

In your example, we'd say "The Greens are a famous family."

There is no reason whatsoever to include the word "the" twice and it would be incorrect to do so.

If the surname included the word "the" (e.g. "John The Green") then we could say "The The Greens are a famous family" - although I am not aware whether any surnames do include the word "the".  (I know that some include "Le" or "La".  You could say "The Le Page family is well known around here".)

Comment: Then, one word cannot have two meanings or two functions at the same time? Not rhetorically but literally

Comment: If we had had more warning, we could have answered better.

Comment: If a word is used ambiguously, it can be understood in two ways at the same time. **He said that in this instance he would *sanction* her actions.**

Comment: You're right, @RonaldSole, but that's not what I understood the question to be about.  (I did, briefly, think it was something along those lines, based on the title of the post - but the body of the question is quite different.)